# How to set Rules event for "Content is viewed" from excluding Teaser view?

Tags: rules, nodes

I set up a Rule that will execute during the "Content is viewed" Event and the action was to show a system message.

It worked and was triggered when I viewed the node. However, when I went to the home page, it was triggered N times, where N is the number of nodes on the /node page.

How do I stop this from happening? The Rule should only fall through on content full view, and exclude the teaser view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your rule add a data comparison called "view-mode" and set it to "Full content".

Answer (score 0):

This might be inefficient but this is what I did:

Added a condition - Data comparison
site:current-page:path == node/[node:nid]

This is to make sure that it is showing up on the actual full /node/nid page and not as a teaser view.

Comment: In data comparison is also "view-mode" and you can set it to "Full content"

Comment: @NigelWaters that's the right answer, you can add it as answer.
radj: you condition will fail if you enable pathauto or an other URL aliasing mechanism.

Comment: @NigelWaters Yes, please add as an answer so I can select it as the correct an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Mathankumar It did not fail because [...:path] is the pure system path, not the URL which can be an alias.